# Regex matching chars around text

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string with chars inside and I would like to match only the chars around a string.

```
"This is a [1]test[/1] string. And [2]test[/2]"
```

Rubular http://rubular.com/r/f2Xwe3zPzo

Currently, the code in the link matches the text inside the special chars, how can I change it?

Update

To clarify my question. It should only match if the opening and closing has the same number.

```
"[2]first[/2] [1]second[/2]"
```

In the code above, only first should match and not second. The text inside the special chars (first), should be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\[[0-9]\]).+?(\[\/[0-9]\])
```

[Permalink](http://rubular.com/r/eXkdVJ8BFi) to the example on Rubular.

**Update**

Since you want to remove the 'special' characters, try this instead:

```
foo = "This is a [1]test[/1] string. And [2]test[/2]"
foo.gsub /\[\/?\d\]/, ""
# => "This is a test string. And test"
```

**Update, Part II**

You only want to remove the 'special' characters when the surrounding tags match, so what about this:

```
foo = "This is a [1]test[/1] string. And [2]test[/2], but not [3]test[/2]"
foo.gsub /(?:\[(?<number>\d)\])(?<content>.+?)(?:\[\/\k<number>\])/, '\k<content>'
# => "This is a test string. And test, but not [3]test[/2]"
```

Comment: Ah ok, i understand. unfortunately the method gsub removes also the text inside the special chars.

`a =  "This is a [1]test[/1] string. And [2]test[/2]"`
`a.gsub /(\[[0-9]\]).+?(\[\/[0-9]\])/, ''`
`=> "This is a  string. And "`

Comment: Ah ok, you want to remove those 'special' characters?

Comment: Sry, yes i'd would like to remove the special chars. I know how to handle gsub, I am only clueless about the regex.

Comment: @nazshal I've updated my answer. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Test your pattern against the OPs requirement of "It should only match if the opening and closing has the same number.", especially against mismatched tags.

Comment: That is really a nice piece of work, thank you very much, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

`\[([0-9])\].+?\[\/\1\]`

`([0-9])` is a capture since it is surrounded with parentheses. The `\1` tells it to use the result of that capture. If you had more than one capture, you could reference them as well, `\2`, `\3`, etc.

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/2AkCfRfqCK)

---

You can also use a [named capture](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing), rather than `\1` to make it a little less cryptic. As in: `\[(?<number>[0-9])\].+?\[\/\k<number>\]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it that uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a block. The idea is to pull strings such as `"[1]test[/1]"` into the block, and there remove the unwanted bits.

```
str = "This is a [1]test[/1] string. And [2]test[/2], plus [3]test[/99]"

r = /
    \[    # match a left bracket
    (\d+) # capture one or more digits in capture group 1 
    \]    # match a right bracket
    .+?   # match one or more characters lazily
    \[\/  # match a left bracket and forward slash
    \1    # match the contents of capture group 1 
    \]    # match a right bracket
    /x

str.gsub(r) { |s| s[/(?<=\]).*?(?=\[)/] }
  #=> "This is a test string. And test, plus [3]test[/99]"
```

Aside: When I first heard of named capture groups, they seemed like a great idea, but now I wonder if they really make regexes easier to read than `\1`, `\2`....